# Android using Ion to upload file

Tags: android, android-ion

In my webservice i have simple upload function which tested by `cUrl` and its work fine without any problem, and I can upload file by `cUrl` successfully, now I want to upload file from android with `Ion` library, but i get this error:

```
unable to parse json
```

my code is:

```
Ion.with(ActivityAccountInfo.this)
                .load(MyApplication.getHostAddress() + "clientUploadPhoto")
                .uploadProgressHandler(new ProgressCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long downloaded, long total) {
                        uploadMessage.setText("" + downloaded + " / " + total);
                    }
                })
                .setTimeout(60 * 60 * 1000)
                .setMultipartFile("userPhoto", "image/*", new File(photoPath))
                .asJsonObject()
                // run a callback on completion
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        if (e != null) {

                        }
                    }
                });
```

and my web function:

```
Route::any('clientUploadPhoto', function () {
    $filename = Request()->file('userPhoto');
    $destinationPath = base_path() . '/upload/';
    $new_filename = time() . '_' . $filename->getClientOriginalName();
    Image::make($filename->getRealPath())->save($destinationPath . $new_filename);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you can upload a multi-part file as a JSON object?

Comment: @cricket_007 i think file must be stream, not jsonObject, is it right? in `Ion` library that using this solution, `cUrl` can upload file successful

Comment: I don't know what cURL command you used, but `.asJsonObject()` doesn't look right for uploading a file.

Comment: @cricket_007 it is: `curl -F "userPhoto=@/home/mahdi/Pictures/wallch-4.jpg" http://192.168.1.35/public/clientUploadPhoto`

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by other solution, after set bitmap into `ImageView` i get bitmap from that with this code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) user_avatar.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

and after that i'm create `Base64` from that:

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes   = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

now i can upload that with `Ion` and i convert that inside server:

php Laravel framework:

```
public function clientUploadPhoto()
{
    $image = Request::json()->get('file');
    $ext = Request::json()->get('ext');

    file_put_contents( base_path() . '/upload/'.time().$ext,base64_decode($image));
}
```